# C# OrderByDescending on value from list in another list

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to order a list (will refer to this list as result) by a value in another list (Redeems).

The result list contains the Redeems list, and I want to order result by the field "SumChosenYear" in the "Redeems" list and get top 20. This is what I've managed to get, and in theory I think it should work.

```
result = result
  .OrderByDescending(input => input.Redeems
     .Select(input2 => input2.SumChosenYear)
     .ToList())
  .Take(20)
  .ToList();
```

However it throws an exception saying "Atleast one object implement IComparable". Why does this happen?

Comment: `OrderByDescending` wants `IComparable` (in order to sort you have to compare); however you return `List<int>` or alike `...Select(input2 => input2.SumChosenYear).ToList()`. Two `List<int>` can't be compared by default (what is bigger `[1, 2, 3]` or `[0, 4, 7]`?)

Comment: Point taken, that makes total sense. How would I go about ordering it by that field then? The field "SumChosenYear" is only a decimal, so ToListing it was a problem on my end. Would it be an idea to have a field in the list "Redeem" with the sum of SumChosenYear?

Comment: How many rows are in the variable result.  I got same error a couple of weeks ago and found the list to be empty.

Comment: Around 277 - they are generated from the database. I solved the problem by adding a field in the result list, with the sum of the value from the sublist

Comment: Probably you want `Max()` or `Min()` or `First()`, `Last()` or alike instead of `ToList()` within `OrderByDescending`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
input.Redeems
     .Select(input2 => input2.SumChosenYear)
     .ToList()
```

returns you a List and because List does not implement IComparable you cannot put this lambda inside [this overload of OrderByDescending extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.110).aspx).

You have basically two options:

**First option**

Cretae your custom implementation of [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) for this list (assuming SumChosenYear property is an int for this purpose):

```
public class SumChosenYearListComparer : IComparer<List<int>>
{
    public int Compare(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        //Your custom comparison... 
    }
}
```

and then use it with [this overload of OrderByDescending extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = result
  .OrderByDescending(input => input.Redeems
     .Select(input2 => input2.SumChosenYear)
     .ToList(), new SumChosenYearListComparer())
  .Take(20)
  .ToList();
```

**Second option**

You can choose which item in this list you want to use in the comparison(maybe the max, min, first or last value or maybe even the sum of all the items).
Assuming you want to comapre using the max value in the list your code could look something like this:

```
var result = result
  .OrderByDescending(input => input.Redeems
     .Max(input2 => input2.SumChosenYear))
  .Take(20)
  .ToList();
```